`<details>` element with `display:contents` broken in Chrome 131?
I've been playing around with Chrome 131's latest release and noticed some interesting changes with <details> and <summary> elements. I wanted to share my findings and see if anyone else has encountered similar behaviour.
Two significant changes in how <details> elements work:

The <details> element can now accept display:flex and display:grid properties.
You can now target the details contents using this new pseudo selector: ::details-content. No more wrapper divs needed.

I've run into what seems to be a bug. Here's a typical markup pattern I tend to work with:
<details open>
    <summary>Hello World</summary>
    <div class="details-content">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</details>

I have a use case for setting the <details> element display property to contents so that I can lay out a group of details elements into a sort of responsive tabbable UI.
When I do this, Chrome seems to ignore the display:contents property entirely. As far as the dev tools are concerned, it's applied correctly, but just ignores it and resolves to the browser's display:block behaviour; and reports it as such too.

I appreciate my use-case may be a bit niche, but I get the impression that something just isn't right since Chrome's update.
I've put together a CodePen to show what I mean. Try previewing this in both Chrome 131 and Firefox; and toggle the &::details-content {... fix.
I do have a workaround/solution. I can conditionally duplicate the grid-column property for browsers which have support for the new pseudo element selector:
details {
  > .details-content {
      margin-block-start: 1rem;
      grid-row: 2; 
      grid-column: 1 / -1;
  }
  
  @supports selector(::details-content) {
    &::details-content {
      grid-column: 1 / -1;
    }
  }
}

I still don't feel comfortable with this though.
Do you think this is intended behaviour or a bug?

Note, despite examples on e.g. MDN, from the spec: “As with all HTML elements, it is not conforming to use the details element when attempting to represent another type of control. For example, tab widgets and menu widgets are not disclosure widgets, so abusing the details element to implement these patterns is incorrect.”

Interesting. I guess the ::details-content pseudo-element either has to generate a box or not. In Chrome 131 it's generating a block container box. hence your details content wrapper element is not part of the grid. An alternative "fix" is to remove that box with
  &[open]::details-content {
    display: contents;
  }

You might find this more attractive as it's passing on the styling of the grid item to your existing wrapper element.
The specifications for ::details-content seem underdone so it's hard to tell if it's a bug. I suspect that it's necessary for ::details-content to generate some sort of box for the display:grid/flex functionality to work sensibly, so it may be unavoidable. I would suggest raising it as bug, pointing out how it breaks previous behaviour and behaviour in other browsers, and see what response you get.
